# How to say "I come from Beijing, China" in German?

Tags: grammar

I am learning German now, I just learned how to say "where do you come from?" in German. I can say "I come from Beijing, China" in English, and I may say "Ich komme aus Beijing. Ich komme aus China." So, can I say "Ich komme aus Beijing, China." in German? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my point of view, that is not a phrase people say in german. There are two ways to tell where you come from:

- You just either tell them the city (if you expect them to know it because of its size or importance). They will hopefully know the country from that without you mentioning it.
- You tell them only the country, because they cannot use the information about the town or city anyway (because they never heard of it)

In my opinion, it is perfectly fine to omit some of the information. If your conversation partner wants to know more, there is nothing wrong with requiring a second question.

Comment: I disagree in one point. Namely, it's common to say "Beijing, China".

Comment: I would really like to know what is wrong with saying `Ich komme aus Beijing, China`?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, it's just not used. So, if someone uses it, than it sounds weird to mother tongue speakers. And sometimes, one doesn't want to sound weird.

Comment: Öfter mal den Film Paris, Texas gucken. Lief in Deutschland unter dem Titel Paris, Texas.

Comment: @user unknown Der wurde in englischer Sprache gedreht und spielt denke ich mal in Amerika -- das ist nun wirklich kein Hinweis darauf, wie man in Deutschland spricht ...

Comment: Gutes Beispiel, @userunknown, auch wenn Texas ja in dem Sinne kein 'Land' ist, sondern lediglich ein Staat.

Comment: @Timbo: Ja, ein Film von Wim Wenders, siehe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris,_Texas_%28film%29 - unter welchem Titel nochmal im dt. Kino? Und welchen Unterschied macht es, ob die Stadt zum Staat oder Land in dem sie liegt in Bezug gesetzt wird? Ändert das die Grammatik?

Comment: @user unknown Die Frage ist doch, ob es Menschen in Deuschland so sagen. Du versuchst doch nur, eine Begründung dafür zu finden, dass es OK ist, eine traditionell amerikanische Formulierung einzudeutschen. Ein Filmtitel eines Films, der in Amerika spielt und auf Englisch gedreht wurde, reicht mir da aber irgendwie nicht ...

Comment: @Timbo: `Can I say` ist die Frage, ob man das so sagen kann, und meine Behauptung ist: Ja, man kann. Wieso Dir der Filmtitel als Beleg nicht reicht sehe ich nicht ein. In der Berichterstattung wurde, soweit ich es noch im Ohr habe, "Paris" immer deutsch ausgesprochen, und nicht `Päriss` wie ein Amerikaner sagen würde. Empfehlen würde ich vielleicht eher "Ich komme aus Beijing in China" aber so recht weiß ich nicht, wieso man beides sagt und wem, und wie spontan das wäre, was alles einen Einfluss auf Wortwahl u. Satzbau haben kann. Ich komm aus Frankfurt (Oder) und fahr nach Neustadt (Weinstr.)

Comment: @Timbo: Heute mittag im Inforadio, eine Sendung über JFK, sicher noch ein paar Tage im Netz verfügbar über eben jenen der in Köln Grüße aus Cologne/Massachuchets, Cologne/Texas und Cologne/New Jersey ausrichtete, und es gab keinen Grund die Formulierung Wort für Wort zu übersetzen, weil es um die Rhetorik ging sich bei den Kölnern einzuschleimen, und es auch kein Zitat, sondern indirekte Rede war.

Comment: @user unknown Ich weiß ja nicht, ob du es merkst, aber alle deine Beispiele beziehen sich auf Orte in den USA. Was zufällig der Ursprung der Formulierung ist. Findest du nicht, dass das ein bisschen einseitig ist? Wenn du jetzt ein Beispiel mit "Ich komme aus Bern, Schweiz" oder "Ich komme aus Göteborg, Schweden" aus dem Hut zauberst, wäre schon viel geholfen. Viel Spaß beim suchen!

Comment: @Timbo: Nein, finde ich nicht, denn es gibt keine Regel, wonach man die Grammatik dem Ort anpasst über den man spricht oder aus dem ein Begriff kommt. Man schreibt auch E-Mail nicht klein, obwohl es ein Substantiv des englischsprachigen Raums ist. Wenn Du dafür aber Beispiele aus dem Hut zaubern willst: Viel Spaß beim Suchen!

Comment: Stell dir einfach mal vor: Auf einer Insel im Pazifik ist die verbreitete Formulierung der Beschreibung der Herkunft das zweimalige Sagen des Ortsnamen, gefolgt von einem Schrei und danach sagen die Bewohner ganz leise das Land. Man KANN sowas sicherlich auch auf deutsch machen, nur stündest du damit ziemlich alleine da ...

Comment: @Timbo: Und was zeigt mir das jetzt? Du sagst doch, dass man es bei amerikanischen Orten nur sagt, weil die Amerikaner das so machen. Ich habe eben gezeigt, dass es ein Sprecher des Inforadios tut, nachdem ich einen Filmtitel in Deutschland schon als Beispiel gebracht habe. An Dir wäre es zu zeigen, wieso "Paris in Texas" als Filmtitel nicht funktioniert hätte.

Comment: Soeben in der Sportschau, "Boxen im Ersten", Ringsprecher Roman Roell stellt die Ringrichter vor, bei Richter No. 2 fiel mir auf "Amsterdam, Niederlande"; dann "Giovanni ... aus Rom, Italien", und "xy aus Kapstadt, Südafrika". Also wenn man 2 Tage lang die Ohren aufmacht hört man es allenthalben. Die Aussage "that is not a phrase people say in german" muss als widerlegt gelten. Im Gegenteil wird sie ständig benutzt. Sicher eine Zeit in der Mediathek abrufbar. Bei den folgenden Kämpfen nach dem Hauptkampf werden die Personen wieder und wieder vorgestellt.

Comment: @detraveller The sentence is wrong, because the name is translated in German. Better say: `Ich komme aus Peking, China.`

Comment: @Timbo: Ich würde das Beispiel von der Pazifikinsel am liebsten mehrfach upvoten, wenn das ginge :) Ich stimme dir zu, dass die Formulierung "Ort, Staat/Land" auf Deutsch an sich nicht üblich ist, aber in Medienproduktionen möglicherweise aufgrund des Einflusses amerikanischer Serien, in denen das meistens recht "cool" klingt, mitunter verwendet wird.

Answer (score 8):

Ich komme aus Beijing in China.

A lot of people will understand the word 'Peking' (incorrectly pronounced [ˈpeːkiŋ] in German) more instantly, which sounds a little naff to people who have been exposed to matters regarding China a bit more, but it was quite normal even among these just 10 to 15 years ago, and it is still widely used in the media.

BTW, I believe you can phrase it this way in English as well: "I come from Beijing in China." The city+comma+state form seems more typical e.g. for people within North America who would say/write something like "I'm from Paris, Texas." (I still have to watch that Wim Wenders movie…) But on the international level there is nothing wrong using 'in'. (Well, except in forms and tabular CVs, where "City, Country" is probably the standard anywhere.)

Comment: @Takkat: You're right. (I've been exposed to China-related things a bit more, so I might be slightly biased.) 'Beijing' is mostly used in the media when citing international names of Chinese organisations, firms, etc. 'Peking' is easier for us westerners to pronounce, *albeit the wrong way*. 'Beijing' is the emerging form since 'Mandarin' Chinese along with the Pinyin transcription system has been spreading for some time, internationally and certainly here in Germany where Pinyin is the standard in teaching Chinese. – I'm going to revise my answer.

Comment: @TehMacDawg: What's _wrong_ with the pronunciation [ˈpeːkiŋ]? I'd say that this is the _correct_ pronunciation _in Germany!_

Comment: It's because of that (IMHO strange) trend that people think one has to pronounce cities as they are pronounced in that country. Try to tell an American that he should not say "Munich" but "München", I don't think you'd be very successful. But in Germany we now are supposed to use names for Chinese cities that are written to give a pronounciation close to the Chinese one when spoken with *English* pronounciation rules.

Comment: @celtschk: Strange to say that this depends on the city. Nobody would pronounce "Paris" like [paˈʁi] or "London" as [ˈlʌndən] in Germany.

Comment: @celtschk: I think it's not at all a strange trend, but rather a very reasonable one, given that it can hardly be useful to create n * m words (n = language count, m = city count), and at the same time even *reduce* chances for communication across languages by removing some of the only mutual points of reference that speakers of two different languages might have. That notwithstanding, certain words have become widespread for cities that already used to be relatively significant in past times, and while I suppose those will gradually be phased out over the next few centuries, they are ...

Comment: ... currently still completely correct alternatives to the original names.

Answer (score 7):

In case we do not only want to tell people the country where we come from but also the city where we live we would put it similar to this:

> Ich komme aus China. Dort lebe ich in Peking.
>   Ich bin Chinese und wohne in Peking.
>   Ich stamme aus China und lebe in Peking.

As always there are many more variants to this. All is in common that we put the extra information in a separate sentence or in a subordinate clause introduced with a conjunction.

In written German it is also possible to put the country a city is in separated by a comma:

> Ich wohne in Langfang, China.

Most people in Germany will know Beijing from its German name *"[Peking](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Peking)"*. Everybody will know that it is the capital of China so there is no need for further explanations. *"Beijing"* on the other hand is not widely used. Most Germans will not even be able to spell it.

Comment: 'Beijing' like /bɛi.dʒiŋ/ (don't know the IPA for tonal notation, which is crucial in spoken Chinese.)

Comment: My preferred way to say both the country and the city would be: _Ich komme aus China, aus Peking._

Comment: Your answer sounds more reasonable, I'll also write it to my notes. Thanks!