# Regel für Abtrennung des Vornamens vom vorangestellten Nachnamen

Tags: spelling, person-names

Wo steht die Regel, dass der vorangestellte Nachname vom nachfolgend geschriebenen Vornamen durch ein Komma getrennt wird?

Comment: Ähnliche Frage: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/6917/266 - wie sagt man es in Beijing, China?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anscheinend wird dies durch DIN 5007 festgelegt. Die Primärquelle habe ich nicht gefunden, aber unter [diesem Link](http://www.ordnung-ohne-stress.de/files/Ordnung-ohne-Stress-MAPPEI-ABC-Standards.pdf) findet man eine entsprechende Wiedergabe. Beachte aber, dass die Namen in Fließtext als `Vorname Nachname` und nicht `Nachname, Vorname` geschrieben werden.

Comment: Danke für den Link. Ist das dann so bindend wie eine Rechtschreibregel?

Comment: Siehe auch: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetische_Sortierung

Comment: @falkb Über den DIN steht nur noch das Grundgesetz. ;-)